ASP.NET CRUD Master Detail saves only a single detail line


@section Scripts {
    @{
        await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");
    }
}
<script>
    function AddItem(btn) {
        var table;
        table = document.getElementById('employeestable');
        var rows = table.getElementsByTagName('tr');
        var rowOuterHtml = rows[rows.length - 1].outerHTML;

        var lastrowIdx = rows.length = 2;

        var nextrowIdx = eval(lastrowIdx) + 1;

        rowOuterHtml = rowOuterHtml.replaceAll('_' + lastrowIdx + '_', '_' + nextrowIdx + '_');
        rowOuterHtml = rowOuterHtml.replaceAll('[' + lastrowIdx + ']', '[' + nextrowIdx + ']');
        rowOuterHtml = rowOuterHtml.replaceAll('_' + lastrowIdx + '_' + nextrowIdx);

        var newRow = table.insertRow();
        newRow.innerHTML = rowOuterHtml;

        var x = document.getElementsByTagName("INPUT");

        for (var cnt = 0; cnt < x.length; cnt++) {
            if (x[cnt].type == "text" && [cnt].id.indexOf('_' + nextrowIdx + '_') > 0)
                x[cnt].value = '';
            else if (x[cnt].type == "number" && [cnt].id.indexOf('_' + nextrowIdx + '_') > 0)
                x[cnt].value = 0;
        }

    }

    function DeleteItem(btn) {

        var table = document.getElementById('employeestable');
        var rows = table.getElementsByTagName('tr');

        if (rows.length == 2) {
            alert("This Row Cannot Be Deleted");
            return;
        }

        $(btn).closest('tr').remove();
    }
</script>
@model TestApplication_timesheet.Models.TimeSheetHeader

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Create";
}

<h1>Create</h1>

<h4>TimeSheetHeader</h4>
<hr />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-action="Create">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="TimeSheetID" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="TimeSheetID" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="TimeSheetID" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="CustomerId" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="CustomerId" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="CustomerId" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="SkillRateId" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="SkillRateId" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="SkillRateId" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Date" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Date" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Date" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div>
                <h6>Details</h6>
                <table class="table table-bordered" id="employeestable">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Employee</th>
                            <th>Total Hours</th>
                            <th style="width:60px;">
                                <button id="btnAddDetailRow" type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-secondary visible" onclick="AddItem(this)">
                                    Add
                                </button>
                            </th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        @for (int i = 0; i < Model.TimeSheetDetails.Count; i++)
                        {
                            <tr>
                               <td>
                                    @Html.EditorFor(x => x.TimeSheetDetails[i].ContractEmployeeId, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    @Html.EditorFor(x => x.TimeSheetDetails[i].TotalHrs, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                                </td>
                                <td style="width:60px;">
                                    <button id="btnremove-@i" type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger visible" onclick="DeleteItem(this)">
                                        Delete
                                    </button>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        }
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>



I'm building a master details page - that is multiple details records with single master record.
But only one detail record is being saved into the data base.
I tried to debug & found that detail loop is getting value only once even though the csthml page has dynamic input controls.
Here is my code for save method:
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using TestApplication_timesheet.Data;
using TestApplication_timesheet.Models;

namespace TestApplication_timesheet.Controllers
{
    public class TimeSheetController : Controller
    {
        private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;

        public TimeSheetController(ApplicationDbContext context )
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            List<TimeSheetHeader> timeSheetHeader = _context.TimeSheetHeader.ToList();
            return View(timeSheetHeader);
        }
        public IActionResult Create() 
        { 
            TimeSheetHeader timeSheetHeader=new TimeSheetHeader();

                timeSheetHeader.TimeSheetDetails.Add(new TimeSheetDetails() { Id = 1 });

            return View("Create", timeSheetHeader);
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Create(TimeSheetHeader timesheetheader)
        {

                _context.TimeSheetHeader.Add(timesheetheader);

                // Iterate through TimeSheetDetails and save each explicitly
                foreach (var detail in timesheetheader.TimeSheetDetails)
                {
                    _context.TimeSheetDetails.Add(detail); // Ensure TimeSheetHeaderId is set
                }

                _context.SaveChanges();


                return RedirectToAction("Index");

        }
    }
}


Expecting the mutiple detail lines are saved to the db.  the create action method saves only one line.  The model class for header and details are set as below.  Tried many solutions from the blogs with no luck. Any help would be appreciated

Obvious question: What's the exact value of timesheetheader when it gets to your POST action?  Specifically timesheetheader.TimeSheetDetails - does it contain multiple timesheets at this point? ie is the issue with the sender rather than the receiver.   The issue is most likely in the UI where you are building the multiple details records to send to the server (be it via js or as a form post).

i think the sender is not sending it properly. my cshtml as below

You can [edit] the question to add a snippet [<>]

Does it work if you don't delete any rows?   The issue is that when you pass an array to an action, it must be consecutive, without any gaps.  As soon as there's a gap, the array stops.   ie [0,1,5,6,7,8] will only pass as [0,1] - removing then re-adding will get array indices such as [0,1,2,2,2,2,10] using the method you have.   You can write your own model binder to handle it or you can make sure there's no gaps.  Easiest option is to add a "virtual removed" hidden input and set this when you remove a row.  Worst option is to re-index every time.

More details here:  https://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx/  (and there's SO answers for this as well)

it doesnt work at all, i tried not clicking delete too

Issue Solved
by adding the below lines in the cshtml
and adding 2 lines in the script
    var lastrowIdx = document.getElementById('hdnLastIndex').value;

    var nextrowIdx = eval(lastrowIdx) + 1;

    document.getElementById('hdnLastIndex').value = nextrowIdx;

